# Azure Pipelines: Dotnet publish fails with exit code 1 after migrating to .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline which is setup to do:

- Use .NET Core SDK 3.1.x
- Dotnet restore
- Dotnet Build
- Dotnet Publish

Use .NET Core task looks like that and it run before all others mentioned above:
[image]

All the jobs are executed successfully apart the **Dotnet Publish**

This job crashes with these errors:
[image]

AND

[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1

[warning]Info: Azure Pipelines hosted agents have been updated to contain .Net Core 3.x SDK/Runtime along with 2.2 & 2.1. Unless you have locked down a SDK version for your project(s), 3.x SDK might be picked up which might have breaking behavior as compared to previous versions.

I tried different version variation for Use .NET Core SDK Job, however all of them lead to the same error.

Publish job:
[image]

Thanks in advance. Appreciate if someone could give me a clue what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Are you hosting your own build agent or using the provided one in Azure?

Comment: provided one in Azure

Comment: Why are you not showing the publish task, **when that is the one causing the issue**?

Comment: Sorry, thought the issue is unlikely with the actual Publish job. Just updated the case with publish job

Comment: Hint: what is `$(buildPlatform)` set to?

Comment: Ups.. doing things in the rush again:
  buildPlatform: 'win10-x64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out that issue had nothing to do with the Azure Pipelines, it was caused by the package referenced in my .csproj:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Xdt.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
```

This package has a dependency for .NETCoreApp 2.0

Found that author created a new package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNet.Xdt#
https://github.com/nil4/dotnet-transform-xdt

Which is now compatible with .NET Core 3.x

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do to install a specific version of dotnet core:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '3.1.101'
```

I the only difference I found you have to specify the SDK version exactly of the SDK build. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunatelly, I have tried it already and it did not work.